# ServiceStack DateTime format problem with CsvRequestLogger

Tags: servicestack

I'm using this setup:

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
  ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;
  ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig<DateTime>.SerializeFn = time => new DateTime(time.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Local).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig<DateTime>.DeSerializeFn = ServiceStack.Text.Common.DateTimeSerializer.ParseDateTime;

  Plugins.Add(new RequestLogsFeature
  {
    RequestLogger = new CsvRequestLogger()
  });

  //...
}
```

And on first run everything is fine, however, when I run my app second time, I'm getting this:

> ServiceStack.CsvRequestLogger[0]
>         Could not read last entry from 'ServiceStack.NetCore.NetCoreLog'
>   System.FormatException: String '10/11/2018 15:01:46' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: ParseDateTime expects a XsdDateTimeFormat ("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ") but it's getting a DefaultDateTimeFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").

Comment: I think you'll have to roll your own function to parse. Since you don't allow a DateTime?, you'll have to decide whether to use TryParse then return a DateTime.MinValue when it's a bad format or Parse that throws an exception when it's a bad format.

Comment: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/647ccf253f2364200b75536e189e95ca1f8be3af/src/ServiceStack.Text/Common/DateTimeSerializer.cs#L345

Answer (score 3):

Your custom Date deserializer can’t parse your custom date serializer.

Also you should [avoid using ambiguous date formats](https://xkcd.com/1179/).